# MySQL JDBC Проблема с русской кодировкой

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, jdbc

При подключении через JDBC указываю кодировку

```
properties.setProperty("user",user);
    properties.setProperty("password",pass);
    properties.setProperty("useUnicode","true");
    properties.setProperty("characterEncoding","utf8");
```

Сама база данных в utf-8, таблица тоже После подключения еще раз указываю что кодировка `statement.execute("SET NAMES utf8");` Толку никакого

Проверял через консоль sql в базу заносится уже битая кодировка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена, я прочитал неправильную книгу в которой уверяли что для хранения больших обьемов текста нужно применять тип данных blob и что varchar не может быть больше 255 символов. При внесении данных из консоли они заносились нормально, но через jdbc всё время была битая кодировка, что сбивало с толку и я думал что проблема в моём коде, после замены типа данных столбца с блоба на варчар (2000) всё заработало!

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
properties.setProperty("user",user);
    properties.setProperty("password",pass);
    properties.setProperty("useUnicode","true");
    properties.setProperty("characterEncoding","cp1251");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,properties);
```

И в настройках Mysql сервера изменить стандартную кодировку `latin1` та что `ISO-88...` на `Cp1251`.
`default-character-set=cp1251`

Comment: Вроде бы заработало только не путем изменения кодировки сервера. Структура таблицы содержит три поля int int и blob. После того как я поменял blob на varchar(1000) то всё заработало. Разве блоб не предназначен для хранения текста? Я полтора дня долбился. Сейчас попробую изменить кодировку сервера...

Comment: @JoyDIR, Тип данных BLOB представляет собой двоичный объект большого размера, который может содержать переменное количество данных.

Comment: Прочитал книгу называется, там уверяли что blob это текст, а varchar не может быть больше 255

Comment: @JoyDIR, может перевод был некорректный

Comment: Если я вносил какую либо запись через консоль, то русская кодировка отображалась нормально, а через jdbc вообще никак, это меня и сбило с толку.

Comment: Книга Head First SQL - v2

Comment: @JoyDIR, проблема решена? :)